# What is the Dirichlet density of all primes whose least residue mod 24 is strictly less than 8

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

What is the Dirichlet density of all primes whose least residue modulo $24$ is strictly less than $8$?
I don't understand the meaning of least residue 
I know the Dirichlet density of a set of primes that conference to $a \bmod m$ is equal to 1/ Euler(m) where the greatest common divisor between $a$ and $m$ is $1$.

Any help is appreciated 
In the note it is 3/Euler(24)
But why

Comment: Dirichlet tells us that each residue class relatively prime to $24$ has the same density, namely $\frac 1{\varphi(24)}=\frac 18$.  The relatively prime residue classes $≤8$ are $1,5,7$.

Comment: What is `Euler(m)`?

Comment: @lulu but what is the meaning of least residue mod 24

Comment: I don't know how to write it in latex it is Euler function @Bernard

Comment: Well, it's not standard terminology.  Still, I think the context makes clear what is intended:  Every integer is congruent to exactly one of $\{0,1,\cdots, 23\} \pmod {24}$.  Every prime $>3$ is congruent to exactly one of $\{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23\}\pmod {24}$.  Given that, the author appears to be after those congruent to $\{1,5,7\}$ as those are $≤8$.

Comment: Is it Euler's totient function?